# Young adult fantasy novel with blind archer who closes his eyes when he shoots. Romance theme

Tags: story-identification

It is a book I read as a child, probably the second book I have ever read, so I don't remember much about it. I can only recall it was a fantasy book for children, the main characters (a boy and a girl) that have to leave their village because of some danger I cannot remember. At some point during their travel, they meet a man who always keeps his eyes closed. The boy asks why and the man responds

> "because if I opened them, it would not make any difference".

So the guy was a blind man but he was so cool he was an archer and even taught the boy how to shoot. With the new skills (I assume the girl learned something from the man too) the two manage to defeat whatever antagonist there was and confess their feelings for each other. There might have been a kiss underwater.

Comment: When were you a child? And where? What language did you read it in? Also, can you [edit] the title to be a bit more descriptive?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Was the whole village in danger? What happened to the other villagers? What about the world was fantastical (was there magic, for example)? What were the characters names? What were the character's ages? Was the blind archer a major character? What was his name? After leaving the village, what adversity did they face? Where were they traveling to? What did the cover look like? Were the characters white/caucasian? Was this young adult fantasy or a book for preteens?